# Span<T> range operator doesn't make sense

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, c#-8.0

I cannot for the life of me understand the logic behind the Range operator of a Span.

I have a the following byte array which contains an IP Protocol header:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   other data                  |    src ip     |    dest ip    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the range operator, I need to use the following values to extract the proper 4 byte arrays:

```
Span<byte> ipHeader = ethernetFrame.IPHeader;
byte[] sourceIpAddress = ipHeader[12..16].ToArray();
byte[] destinationIpAddress = ipHeader[16..20].ToArray();
```

If instead, I use the Slice method, I end up with:

```
Span<byte> ipHeader = ethernetFrame.IPHeader;
byte[] sourceIpAddress = ipHeader.Slice(12, 4).ToArray();
byte[] destinationIpAddress = ipHeader.Slice(16, 4).ToArray();
```

What is the logic behind the range operator that requires me to give an end value that's 1 past the actual ending index value?

I'm also curious from a performance perspective (because this particular code block runs millions of times per minute), would using Slice be more efficient anyway?

Comment: The part that messes me up is that array[^1] gives you the last element, but to include the last element in a range, I need to do array[^3..^0]. Also the fact that array[^1..^0] returns 1 element. Seriously, people.

Comment: The question is more why are you doing IP protocol parsing in C#, and in a business hot loop at that, and not in C or C++? Anyways the answer resides in Dijkstra 1982 note https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I cannot for the life of me understand the logic behind the Range operator of a Span.

It's worth noting that this isn't specific to Span - ranges in C# are *always* expected to have an exclusive upper bound. (See the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) for more.)

> What is the logic behind the range operator that requires me to give an end value that's 1 past the actual ending index value?

It's just an exclusive upper bound. Upper bounds are very often exclusive, and that has multiple benefits. For example, notice how you have two `|` dividers in your picture? Those are at index 12 and 16 - that's the upper bound of the range before, and the lower bound of the range after. The same number is useful in both places, so you don't need to start adding or subtracting one.

Note that exclusive upper bounds are really common in `for` loops as well. If you wanted to manually copy that src IP address, I suspect you'd do something like:

```cs
for (int index = 12; index < 16; index++)
{
    // Copy item at index
}
```

I consider that much more idiomatic than using an *inclusive* upper bound:

```cs
for (int index = 12; index <= 15; index++)
{
    // Copy item at index
}
```

It also works naturally with ranges specified as start and length:

```
for (int index = start; index < start + length; index++)
{
    // Copy item at index
}
```

(Or conversely, with exclusive upper bounds you can find the length just by subtracting the start from the end, without any "add one" parts.)

> I'm also curious from a performance perspective (because this particular code block runs millions of times per minute), would using Slice be more efficient anyway?

The range operator will slice the span already. What's potentially inefficient is constructing new byte arrays - if you can avoid that, and use the spans directly, that will be more efficient.

Comment: It will take me a bit of time to get my head around it, now that you've drawn it out, I understand it. Its just that when you're looking at it from a byte array perspective, it's not entirely intuitive.

In the intermediate, I decompiled the IL that is generated for a Range operation vs a Slice, and the compiler generates roughly 6 more operations for Range operations vs Slices.

As for avoiding the byte array copy, unfortunately, the constructor for System.Net.IPAddress doesn't accept Span<byte> as a parameter. :-/

Comment: @jscarle: It seems intuitive to me, but I guess I'm used to thinking in terms of exclusive ranges. In terms of performance, I really wouldn't be worried about those extra 6 instructions. I believe they're basically performing a subtraction - I suspect there are very, very few situations where that difference would prove significant.

Comment: I normally wouldn't be trying to optimize at such a microscopic level, it just that the code in particular I'm writing will run 24/7 and will process terabytes of data, so I'm trying to squeeze every last bit of performance using code optimisations while at the same time attempting to conserve a balance of simplification and class structures that will allow the final class to be easily integrated into other projects.

Comment: @jscarle: So as ever, the key is to measure. Try it using range and try it using slice. Given that you're creating an array and copying data though, I'd be surprised if a single subtraction became relevant. (And *anything* about the network is going to dwarf that...)

Comment: @jscarle: You may want to investigate the option of calling the `IPAddress(long)` constructor instead of passing in a byte array. Although again, I'd expect *doing* anything with an IPAddress to take longer than the constructor anyway.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting link to the design decision (inclusive vs exclusive) can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-01-22.md).

The conclusions in the report are:

- It allows a.Length as an endpoint without adding/subtracting 1.
- It lets the end of one range be the beginning of the next without overlap
- It avoids ugly empty ranges of the form x..x-1